# I want to sort an array of objects in JavaScript with Two properties Boolean value and Int

Tags: javascript

I want to sort an array of objects in JavaScript with Two properties Boolean value and Int value.I want Output like this :

```
{
    first_name: 'sumeet',
    last_name: 'Prentice',
    offerApplicable: 'TRUE',
    price: 40
}, {
    first_name: 'Pirate',
    last_name: 'Prentice',
    offerApplicable: 'TRUE',
    price: 50
}, {
    first_name: 'Lazslo',
    last_name: 'Jamf',
    offerApplicable: 'TRUE',
    price: 60
}, {
    first_name: 'jitendra',
    last_name: 'Prentice',
    offerApplicable: 'TRUE',
    price: 101
}
```

All object with true values are first also sorted with price and then all object having boolean value as false. i am able to sort them by boolean value but i want to sort them by price as well.

i have tried this

```
var objs = [ 
    { first_name: 'Lazslo', last_name: 'Jamf'   ,offerApplicable: 'TRUE' ,price: 60 },
    { first_name: 'Pig',    last_name: 'Bodine'  , offerApplicable: 'FALSE' ,price: 100},
    { first_name: 'Pirate', last_name: 'Prentice' ,offerApplicable: 'TRUE' ,price: 50},
    { first_name: 'nithesh',    last_name: 'Bodine'  , offerApplicable: 'FALSE' ,price: 40},
    { first_name: 'sumeet', last_name: 'Prentice' ,offerApplicable: 'TRUE' ,price: 40},
    { first_name: 'mahesh',    last_name: 'Bodine'  , offerApplicable: 'FALSE' ,price: 40},
    { first_name: 'jitendra', last_name: 'Prentice' ,offerApplicable: 'TRUE' ,price: 101}
];
function compare(a,b) {
    var aConcat = a["offerApplicable"] + a["price"];
      var bConcat = b["offerApplicable"] + b["price"];
  if (aConcat < bConcat )
    return 1;
  if (aConcat > bConcat )
    return -1;
  return 0;

}

console.log(objs.sort(compare));
```

i am getting output like this

> first_name : "Lazslo" last_name : "Jamf" offerApplicable : "TRUE"
>   price : 60
>
> :first_name : "Pirate" last_name : "Prentice" offerApplicable : "TRUE"
>   price : 50
>
> first_name : "sumeet" last_name : "Prentice" offerApplicable : "TRUE"
>   price : 40
>
> first_name : "jitendra" last_name : "Prentice" offerApplicable :
>   "TRUE" price : 101
>
> first_name : "nithesh" last_name : "Bodine" offerApplicable : "FALSE"
>   price : 40
>
> first_name : "mahesh" last_name : "Bodine" offerApplicable : "FALSE"
>   price : 40
>
> first_name : "Pig" last_name : "Bodine" offerApplicable : "FALSE"
>   price : 100

any help thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in little more steps.

First, get all true and false components in different arrays.

smth like this

```
const trueEntities = defaultArray.filter(e => e.offerApplicable === 'TRUE');
const falseEntities = defaultArray.filter(e => e.offerApplicable === 'FALSE');
```

then sort this arrays by price

```
const sortedByPriceTrue = trueEntities.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
const sortedByPriceFalse =  falseEntities.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
```

and then simply return/use in variable concated arrays

```
return sortedByPriceTrue.concat(sortedbyPriceFalse);
```

i know this solution maybe slower then one operation, but much more readable

p.s. edited, first solution didn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

```
objs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.price - b.price);
});

objs.sort(function (a, b) {
    var price1 = (a.offerApplicable === 'TRUE');
    var price2 = (b.offerApplicable === 'TRUE');
    return price2 - price1;
});
```

First, we sort the values by price & then, sort the value by offerApplicable field.

Combined Solution:

```
objs.sort(function (a, b) {
    var price1 = (a.offerApplicable === 'TRUE');
    var price2 = (b.offerApplicable === 'TRUE');
    return price2 - price1 || a.price - b.price;
});
```

Comment: you assume a stable sorting, which is not granted.

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the criteria for the rewturn value of the sort function of [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

The first part

```
(b.offerApplicable === 'TRUE') - (a.offerApplicable === 'TRUE')
```

performes a check if the value of `offerApplicable` is `'TRUE'`. A comparison with `true` moves the item to the bottom, therfore we need to switch the check with `a` and `b`.

The second part

```
a.price - b.price
```

is only evaluated if the previous delta is zero, then the delta of price is returned.

```js
var array = [{ first_name: 'Lazslo', last_name: 'Jamf', offerApplicable: 'TRUE', price: 60 }, { first_name: 'Pig', last_name: 'Bodine', offerApplicable: 'FALSE', price: 100 }, { first_name: 'Pirate', last_name: 'Prentice', offerApplicable: 'TRUE', price: 50 }, { first_name: 'nithesh', last_name: 'Bodine', offerApplicable: 'FALSE', price: 40 }, { first_name: 'sumeet', last_name: 'Prentice', offerApplicable: 'TRUE', price: 40 }, { first_name: 'mahesh', last_name: 'Bodine', offerApplicable: 'FALSE', price: 40 }, { first_name: 'jitendra', last_name: 'Prentice', offerApplicable: 'TRUE', price: 101 }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (b.offerApplicable === 'TRUE') - (a.offerApplicable === 'TRUE') || a.price - b.price;
});    

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```